# Django Jquery Get URL Conf

Tags: ajax, django, templates, get, urlconf

Ok, so I'm trying to call the function

```
def user_timetable(request, userid):
    user = get_object_or_404(TwobooksUser,id = userid)
    timeSlots = TimeSlot.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    rawtimeslots = []
    for timeSlot in timeSlots:
        newSlot = {
            'userid': timeSlot.user.id,
            'startTime': str(timeSlot.startTime),
            'endTime': str(timeSlot.endTime),
        }
        rawtimeslots.append(newSlot)
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(rawtimeslots))
```

through the javascript in

```
{% include 'elements/header.html' %}

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.get('/books/personal{{ user.id }}/timetable/', {}, function(data) {

                data = JSON.parse(data);
                var events = new Array();
                for (var i in data) {
                    events.push({
                        id: data[i].id,
                        title: '{{ request.user.name }}',
                        start: Date.parse(data[i].startTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                        end: Date.parse(data[i].endTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                        allDay: false
                    });
                }
```

where the above exists in a template that's being rendered (I think correctly).

The url conf that calls the function user_timetable is

```
   url(r'^books/personal/(?P<userid>\d+)/timetable/$',twobooks.ajax.views.user_timetable),
```

But, user_timetable isn't being called for some reason.

Can anyone help?

EDIT-
Ok the original problem was that the template was not being rendered correctly, as the url in firebug comes to '/books/personalNone/timetable/' , which is incorrect.

I'm rendering the template like this -

```
def renderTimetableTemplate(request):
    #if request.POST['action'] == "personalTimetable":
    user = request.user
    return render_to_response(
        'books/personal.html',
        {
        'user': user,
        },
        context_instance = RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Is there a mistake with this?

Comment: Did you looked at the ajax request using firebug or something. Have a look at the source of your page (in the browser) and check the URL of `$.get()`.

Comment: ok, I just did that and I think I found the problem - $.get('/books/personalNone/timetable/') is what is happening.

Which means that I'm not rendering the template correctly, but I'm not sure what mistake I'm making- can you look at the edited code above?

Answer (score 0):

There is a slash missing after "personal"

```
  $.get('/books/personal{{ user.id }}/timetable/', {}, function(data) {
```

should be

```
  $.get('/books/personal/{{ user.id }}/timetable/', {}, function(data) {
```

Btw. you should use the {% url %} template tag.

Comment: what other problem could it be?

Comment: in fact, I did a print "if working" in the function user_timetable, and it's not printing, which means the function is not being called

Comment: please copy the url you request into your browser and see what the response is. maybe you have an error in your view.

Comment: er, it returns a list of TimeSlot objects

Comment: what shows up in firebug, then? look at the request and response data. do they match the format you except on processing the data?

Comment: ok, I put in alerts in teh javascript and they're not showing, suggesting that teh template's not being rendered- can you see any syntax errors, or any other errors?

Comment: as told several times (also by others): use firebug. you can see javascript errors and debug the ajax-interaction.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the data you're converting to JSON and passing to the script, and the data that the script is expecting. You are passing a `userId` element in each timeslot, whereas the script is expecting just `id`.

This error should have shown up in your browser's Javascript console, and would be even easier to see in Firebug (or Chrome's built-in Developer Tools).